# Occurrence of nothing, not even space

Tags: python, string, count

I was going through something when i came across this...

```
a = 'hello'

print(a.count('l'))

print(a.count(''))
```

Output is :

```
2

6
```

Can anyone explain why the second output is 6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` here returns the number of occurences of your substring, here a `''` string.

There are indeed six `''` in hello, between each char:

```
print(''.count(''))  # >> 1

# You could symbolize it like that:
print('a'.count(''))  # >> 2

# is equivalent to:
print('|a|'.count('|'))  # >> 2
```